# Asynctask (progressDialog) - Failed to set damage region EGL_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: android-asynctask, opengl-es, progressdialog, egl

Help me - I am really stuck on the following issue:

The exception is thrown outside the scope of JVM and cannot be handled unless you know the NDK.

```
03-23 17:48:24.463 18768-18913/se.android.appinfo E/Parcel: fcntl(F_DUPFD_CLOEXEC) failed in Parcel::read, i is 0, fds[i] is -1, fd_count is 1, error: Too many open files
03-23 17:48:24.464 18768-18913/se.android.appinfo I/OpenGLRenderer: Surface query width is 1440
03-23 17:48:24.464 18768-18913/se.android.appinfo A/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set damage region on surface 0x7edceec8c0, error=EGL_BAD_ACCESS
03-23 17:48:24.467 18768-18913/se.android.appinfo A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 18913 (RenderThread)
```

I guess the last ones about EGL and OpenGL ES is relevant here?

I have struggled hours and googled about it and cannot find any solutions. And this problem is new to me - this has never occurred to me - I made apps before using Asynctask and showing a progressdialog while loading.

The crash occurs somewhere in between the mainthread and backgroundthread. It does not occur every time, maybe 50% or something. When the crash comes its when the doInBackground is done or almost done and onPostExecute is to be called.

Please - take a notice of my source and help me if you suspect anything that throws the exception (Fatal signal).

source - custom class extending AsyncTask

```
 public class Async_loader extends AsyncTask <String, Integer, String> implements AppInfoRetriever.ProgressInterface {

private Context context;
private AppInfoRetriever appInfoRetriever;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public Async_loader(Context context, AppInfoRetriever appInfoRetriever) {

    this.context = context;
    this.appInfoRetriever = appInfoRetriever;
    this.appInfoRetriever.setProgressInterface(this);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.show();

}

public String doInBackground(String ... params) {

    try {
        appInfoRetriever.retrieve();
    } catch(PackageManager.NameNotFoundException nnfe) {

        nnfe.printStackTrace();
    }
    appInfoRetriever.splitToUserSystemApps();

    return "loading done";
}

@Override
public void onProgressUpdate(final Integer ... values) {

    progressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
    progressDialog.setMessage("parsing apps: " + values[0]);
}


public void onPostExecute(String result) {


    System.err.println(result);
    progressDialog.dismiss();
}

/**
 * Callback från AppInfoRetriever
 * @param nItems
 * @param index
 */
@Override
public void appLoadingProgress(int nItems, int index) {

    publishProgress(index);

 }
}
```

Good to know: Since I want to decouple code I let the AppInfoRetriever parse the apps and while parsing sending (via an interface) information back to Async_loader. I thought this may be the problem but I've tried to lift in the code to Async_loader but no success.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? (I'm facing this same problem and haven't been able to figure it out!)